# Unpacking AuthError (to e.g. Dict) with Firebase-Admin in Python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I wrote a small function to create an user with firebase-admin. However, I am unable to catch the response as it is in a weird unusable format. I guess I have to format it to a dict in order to be able to extract the right properties:

My function:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import auth

cred   = firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate(cert_json)
app    = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, config)
bucket = storage.bucket(app=app)

def create_user(email):
    # Creates a new user, checks if user already exists
    try:
        return auth.create_user(email=email)
    except BaseException as e:
        return e
```

`e` looks as follows:

[image]

I am interested in extracting the "message" property. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admin SDK uses the `requests` library to make HTTP calls.

```
try:
    return auth.create_user(email=email)
except auth.AuthError as e:
    req_error = e.detail # req_error is a requests.exceptions.RequestException
    response = req_error.response # response is a requests.Response
    binary_content = response.content # response content as bytes
    json_content = response.json() # parsed json representation
```